# Unable to find ProcessingReport class in the Json-schema-validator 2.1.6 but the method JsonSchema.validate returns an object of that type

Tags: json, validation

I am trying to validate a json schema using the json-schema-validator 2.1.6. The class JsonSchema has a method validate(jsonfile) which returns the class ProcessingReport but there is no as ProcessingReport or i am not able to spot it. I tried with 2.1.8 as well but same issue. Can anyone who has used it before pt out what i am missing ?

```
ProcessingReport report; // No such Class is present in the jar

report = schema.validate(good);
```

This code is given in one of there examples.

I got the jar from [here](https://bintray.com/fge/maven/json-schema-validator/view) . I was looking for the version 2.0.1 (which is the stable version)  but there was no binary available of that version so i am forced to use a development version.

Comment: Could you please add a link to the github page which has the api specs/docs ?

Comment: https://github.com/fge/json-schema-validator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ProcessingReport class is present in json-schema-core  ( http://fge.github.io/json-schema-core/stable/index.html )

You'll need to add https://github.com/fge/json-schema-core binaries to your path.